# How to trigger nightly builds at different times so load is spread out

Tags: jenkins

I will have many different jobs running sonar. I would like these to all run nightly, but at different times so the load is spread out.

All these jobs are configured from a generic config xml, so I'd ideally like the scheduling instructions to be the same.

It seems like using random numbers within a particular timeframe would be a good choice. But open to better solutions.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could set the build executors to one so they'd all queue up and build one after the other

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found an out of the box solution for this (see my answer below). But curious about build executors and how to set them. Can you post a link to docs please?

Comment: I think I see what you mean - set them up to all use the same slave? That is already the case, but they don't always queue up. That is only the case if the slave is low on resources

Comment: No, check your global settings, you can configure the number of executors, so jenkins will only build one project at a time (default is 2)

Comment: Ok good to know. Thats not feasible since this instance is shared among many projects, and they would not like to queue up builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer right after I posted this.

```
H H(0-7) * * 1-5
```

Builds some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM monday thru friday

More info [at the Jenkins docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/hudson/triggers/TimerTrigger/help-spec.html)